# "Принять меры" или "предпринять меры"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *Принять меры* или *предпринять меры*?

Comment: Возможно, вам будет интересна эта статья  [Что нам следует принять,дабы меры предпринять( о значениях глаголов "принять" и "предпринять"](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.49)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта, но они имеют различные оттенки значений. Мера - это действие или совокупность действий, средств для осуществления, достижения чего-л.

1) Обычно меры принимаются, то есть совершаются или осуществляются с целью поддержки явлений позитивных или борьбы с негативом,например:

"Он осматривал все их заведения по дороге и хотел принять меры для исправления самой дороги".

Так вот, необходимо принять меры, а то получается какая-то неприятная чепуха.  (М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита).
Меры принять, меры принять, меры принять! ― страшно закипятился и Николай Парфенович, ― иначе положительно невозможно! (Ф. М. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы).

2) Иногда (что случается значительно реже) меры предпринимаются, то есть опять же осуществляются или совершаются, но приставка ПРЕД подчеркивает предупредительный характер этих мер, например:

Сейчас экологи призывают все страны этого региона предпринять меры для спасения Мертвого моря.

Остается предпринять меры к временному ограждению себя от ее вмешательства в мою жизнь (П. И. Чайковский).

Comment: Спасибо, София!

Answer (score 2):

Принять меры - это широко используемое устойчивое сочетание,а глагол "предпринять" обычно используется со словами "усилия, шаги (по)"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!