# Каково значение приставки ПРЕД в глаголе "предпринять"?

Tags: словообразование

**Принять** ― многозначное слово, но обычно во всех случаях просматривается значение **приблизить к себе**, даже в устойчивых выражениях вида **принять решение ― решить.**

Можно **принять или предпринять решительные меры** (вроде бы заранее, во избежание возможных негативных последствий, здесь значение ПРЕД здесь понятно). **Но вот путешествие можно только предпринять** (= совершить) ― **почему?**

**Предпринять как приступить к чему-либо тоже не очень ясно.** Предпринять издание, потом производство чего-либо, а далее уже просматривается и ***предприниматель.***

Из словаря:

**ПРИНЯТЬ** 13. что. **Совершить, осуществить то, что выражено существительным.** П. решение (решить). П. смерть (умереть). П. участие в чём-л. П. присягу. П. меры. П. на себя обязательства, труд что-л. сделать.

**ПРЕДПРИНЯТЬ,**  св. что. **Приступить** к осуществлению чего-л. П. исследование, издание журнала. Незамедлительно п. шаги к примирению. // **Сделать, осуществить, совершить.** П. решительные меры. П. путешествие. Срочно п. ещё одну попытку.

Comment: Вас может заинтересовать [это обсуждение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36602/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b) и, особенно, статья по ссылке из комментария к тому вопросу.

Comment: Да, спасибо, статью надо внимательно прочитать. Интересен сам факт превращения предварительно начатого действия в совершённое.